# Apache and long runnig servlets

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

I have an webapp deployed on 4 jboss instances and there is an apache 2.2.15 (mod_proxy, libs: DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_jk/1.2.31) webserver doing the load balancing. The application uses sticky-sessions and sometimes a long running request puts a load balancer member on an error state because of the request timeout and all the other requests made from sessions that are on this member are redirected to another jboss and since there is no session replication the users are presented to the login screen again on the other server.
From what I have been reading it seens that if I change the retry parameter on the BalancerMember to 0 this will not occur anymore. Is that correct or do I need to change another thing?

Listen [IP]:[porta_http]

```
    ServerName app.caixa

    CustomLog /logs/apache2/app/app.caixa-access.log combined

    ErrorLog /logs/apache2/app/app.caixa-error.log



    RedirectMatch ^/$ /app/

    ProxyPass /app/ balancer://app/app/

    ProxyPassReverse /app/ balancer://app/app/



    ProxyPass /app_web/ balancer://app/app_web/

    ProxyPassReverse /app/ balancer://app/app_web/

    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEIDapp=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED



    <Proxy balancer://app>

            BalancerMember ajp://[IP_ServAPP]:[porta_AJP] route=node1 retry=180 connectiontimeout=300000ms ping=500ms lbset=0

            BalancerMember ajp://[IP_ServAPP]:[porta_AJP] route=node2 retry=180 connectiontimeout=300000ms ping=500ms lbset=0

            BalancerMember ajp://[IP_ServAPP]:[porta_AJP] route=node3 retry=180 connectiontimeout=300000ms ping=500ms lbset=1

            BalancerMember ajp://[IP_ServAPP]:[porta_AJP] route=node4 retry=180 connectiontimeout=300000ms ping=500ms lbset=1

            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEIDapp

    </Proxy>



    Include include_status_balancer.conf
```

Comment: try it out and let us know outcome...

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to the environment so I don't know if it will work. I need to give instructions to someone (I don't know who) and they will try so I wanted to know if is just this since I don't have experience with this problem.